plot local linear equivalent kernel at boundary or in interior in R (or Python) for local linear regression
I want to visulize the local linear equivalent kernel, say FIGURE 6.4 in ESL available  at https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/  (ESLII_print12_toc.pdf, page 196 therein)
which reads

and shows

I try to do
### data from FIGURE 6.1
set.seed(1)
X = runif(100)
e = rnorm(100, sd =1/3)
f = function(x) sin(4*x)
Y = f(X) + e

### Epanechnikov kernel: eqs. 6.3 and 6.4
D = function(x) 3/4*(1-x^2)*(abs(x) <= 1) 
K = function(x, x0, lambda=0.2) D(abs(x - x0)/lambda)

### Local Linear Equivalent Kernel (LLEK): eqs. 6.8 and 6.9
LLEK <- function(x0, X, lambda=0.2) {
  b = c(1,x0)
  N = length(X)
  B = cbind(1, X) # Regression matrix B
  W = matrix(0, N, N) # Weight matrix W
  for (i in 1:N) {
    W[i, i] = K(X[i], x0) # Diagonal elements of W
  }
  L = t(b) %*% solve(t(B) %*% W %*% B) %*% t(B) %*% W
  return(list(x=X, l=L))
}

op = par(mfrow=c(1,2))

### plot FIGURE 6.4 (left)
plot(X, Y, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(-1.5, 2), ylab='', xlab = '') #scatter points
curve(f, add = T, lwd=2, col = 'blue') #true line
x0 = 0.05 # particular value at Boundary point
eq_ker = LLEK(x0, X)
points(eq_ker$x, eq_ker$l, col="green", pch=19) #equivalent kernel l_i(x0)

### plot FIGURE 6.4 (right)
plot(X, Y, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(-1.5, 2), ylab='', xlab = '') #scatter points
curve(f, add = T, lwd=2, col = 'blue') #true line
x0 = 0.5 # particular value in Interior point
eq_ker = LLEK(x0, X)
points(eq_ker$x, eq_ker$l, col="green", pch=19) #equivalent kernel l_i(x0)

par(op)

and it gives

that shows very different! How can I fix it?
